# constant term in Matlab principal component regression (pcr) analysis

Tags: matlab, components, regression, principal

I am trying to learn principal component regression (pcr) with Matlab. I use this guide here: http://www.mathworks.fr/help/stats/examples/partial-least-squares-regression-and-principal-components-regression.html

it's really good, but I just cannot understand one step:

we do the PCA and the regression, nice and clear:

```
[PCALoadings,PCAScores,PCAVar] = princomp(X);
betaPCR = regress(y-mean(y), PCAScores(:,1:2));
```

And then we adjust the first coefficient:

```
betaPCR = PCALoadings(:,1:2)*betaPCR;
betaPCR = [mean(y) - mean(X)*betaPCR; betaPCR];
yfitPCR = [ones(n,1) X]*betaPCR;
```

How come that the coefficient needs to be `'mean(y) - mean(X)*betaPCR'` for the constant one factor? Can you explain that to me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a math question, not a coding question. Your PCA extracts a set of features and puts them in a matrix, which gives you `PCALoadings` and `PCAScores`. Pull out the first two principal components and their loadings, and put them in their own matrix:

```
W = PCALoadings(:, 1:2)
Z = PCAScores(:, 1:2)
```

The relationship between `X` and `Z` is that `X` can be approximated by:

```
Z = (X - mean(X)) * W      <=>      X ~ mean(X) + Z * W'                  (1)
```

The intuition is that `Z` captures most of the "important information" in `X`, and the matrix `W` tells you how to transform between the two representations.

Now you can do a regression of `y` on `Z`. First you have to subtract the mean from `y`, so that both the left and right hand sides have mean zero:

```
y - mean(y) = Z * beta + errors                                           (2)
```

Now you want to use that regression to make predictions for `y` from `X`. Substituting from equation (1) into equation (2) gives you

```
y - mean(y) = (X - mean(X)) * W * beta

            = (X - mean(X)) * beta1
```

where we have defined `beta1 = W * beta` (you do this in your third line of code). Rearranging:

```
y = mean(y) - mean(X) * beta1 + X * beta1

  = [ones(n,1) X] * [mean(y) - mean(X) * beta1; beta1]

  = [ones(n,1) X] * betaPCR
```

which works out if we define

```
betaPCR = [mean(y) - mean(X) * beta1; beta1]
```

as in your fourth line of code.

Comment: Thanks so much, you've helped a lot!